# Find $(C_1,C_2,d)$ such that $C_1x^d\le\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2x}\le C_2x^d$ on $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Consider the function $f(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x}$. Find some constants $C_1$, $C_2$ and $d$ such that, for every $x>0$, $C_1 x^d \le f(x) \le C_2x^d$.

My professor said $d$ should be $-\frac{1}{2}$,

I have figured out that $f(x)\leq \int f(x)dn=0.5\pi x^{-0.5}$

How to do the other side?

Comment: If you want people to invest in your existential problems, you must invest in typesetting. This is quite hard to read.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$ is monotonically decreasing  in $n$ so $$\int _1 ^\infty \frac{dn}{1+n^2x}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2x} \le  \int _0 ^\infty \frac{dn}{1+n^2x}$$

Comment: ...Which leads to $$\frac\pi{2\sqrt{x}}-1\leqslant f(x)\leqslant\frac\pi{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: @uniquesolution : Sorry, it's my first time asking question, i will better my typesetting next time.

Comment: @WW1 : Thank you very much !!

Comment: @Did : Thank you very much !!  (and the editing too!!)

Comment: Guys we have a problem, The left hand side is not correct. Help!!

Comment: "The left hand side is not correct." Why do you think so? Which left hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2x} \geq \sum_{n^2 \geq  1/x} \frac{1}{2 n^2 x} \geq \frac{1}{2x} \int^\infty_{1/\sqrt{x}} \frac{\,dn}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.
$$